# getElementById не может найти уже существующий элемент

Tags: javascript, css

Пытаюсь изменить css код при помощи js. Как я понимаю, он не находит элемент с таким id, но в html он есть. Функция запихнута в DOMContentLoaded, да и сам скрип подключается в конце body. Искал ответ в инете - не нашел.

```
function clear(){
    for(var i =0;i<5;i++){
        document.getElementById(i+1).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Пробовал i+1 запихать в ToString - не помогло.
Что я делаю не так?
html:

```
 <img name="slider_img" id="1" src="media/1.jpg">
 <img name="slider_img" id="2" src="media/2.jpg">
 <img name="slider_img" id="3" src="media/3.jpg">
 <img name="slider_img" id="4" src="media/4.jpg">
 <img name="slider_img" id="5" src="media/5.jpg">
```

```js
function clear() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document.getElementById(i + 1).style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}

clear();
```

```html
<img name="slider_img" id="1" src="media/1.jpg">
<img name="slider_img" id="2" src="media/2.jpg">
<img name="slider_img" id="3" src="media/3.jpg">
<img name="slider_img" id="4" src="media/4.jpg">
<img name="slider_img" id="5" src="media/5.jpg">
```

Comment: Приведи пример с разметкой. Код, в принципе, рабочий

Comment: Если `getElementById` - возвращает `null` - значит элемента с указанным `id` - нет. Либо он еще не добавлен, либо уже удален, либо ошибка в `id`

Comment: @Grundy, добавил, или надо было весь блок кода?

Comment: перенес твой код в сниппет. Обрати внимание - все работает, ошибок нет

Comment: попробуй отредактировать код так, чтобы ошибка воспроизвелась

Comment: Нашел решение. Я вызвал clear из другой функции. Именно эта функция была в DOMContentLoaded(Сама clear не была в нем). Решил тем что вместо `Clear();` я писал `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", clear);`

Comment: Все еще непонятно. Либо ты неверное указал в тексте вопроса где расположены скрипты и когда вызываются скрипты, либо у тебя и так все работало. Именно поэтому и нужно добавить в вопрос пример, в котором ошибка воспроизводится

Comment: Уважаемый, переименуйте функцию `clear()` [от греха подальше](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-clear). Например, в `fClear()`.

Answer (score 2):

смотрите, что происходит у вас

```
<script />
<img />
```

1. выполняется js код
2. создаются элементы

поскольку скрипт расположен выше html элементов и значит вызывается раньше элементов, то этих элементов на момент вызова скрипта пока в документе **не существует**

что можно сделать - сначала html код, потом вызов скрипта:

```
<img />
<script />
```

или чтобы хотя бы вызов функции был ниже элементов

```
<script>function clear(){...}</script>
<img />
<script>clear()</script>
```

или создавайте элементы динамически  с помощью JS и до вызова функции `clear()`

P.S.

```
<body>

<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    clear();
});

function clear(){
    for(var i =0;i<5;i++){
        document.getElementById(i+1).style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}

</script>
    
 <img name="slider_img" id="1" src="media/1.jpg">
 <img name="slider_img" id="2" src="media/2.jpg">
 <img name="slider_img" id="3" src="media/3.jpg">
 <img name="slider_img" id="4" src="media/4.jpg">
 <img name="slider_img" id="5" src="media/5.jpg">

</body>
```

так тоже все работает

Comment: в вопросе же указано: _Функция запихнута в DOMContentLoaded, да и сам скрип подключается в конце body_

Comment: @Grundy приведённый автором поста код у меня в тестовом примере замечательно сработал когда script был ниже элементов

Comment: Поэтому ты решил придумать свой вопрос и сам на него ответить? :-D

Comment: @Grundy, с `DOMContentLoaded` тоже все работает

Comment: Нужно знать какая именно разметка у автора вопроса, где и как подключаются и когда вызываются скрипты. Сейчас ты просто придумываешь как это могло бы быть, а могло и не быть